# Lumia Camera (it's the default app for me) opens nonstop suddenly

Tags: camera, buttons, nokia-lumia-830

So earlier I spilled some diet cola and some made its way onto my phone screen and case. I dried the soda. That was 7 hours ago. Now suddenly since an hour and a half ago my phone camera app has been opening by itself repeatedly. This has been going on ever since.

-my phone is the Nokia Lumia 830

-I took off the back cover and wiped the camera button area a little bit and no use

-soft reset doesn't work

-takes pictures by itself as if i have held the camera button to open the app and continue to hold it so it takes a picture.

Can someone try to find out why this problem is happening and how to fix it? I'm trying to sleep now and I have to shut off my phone to try to stop this.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've got excess moisture (still) inside the phone - you may be able to drawy this out by sealing in a plastic bag with some Silica gel, or if you haven't got that to hand, some people have had sucess with uncooked rice.

If neither option works, you may need to visit a service centre.

Comment: The rice has worked wonders for me several times.